# Why does RegExp exec() not work properly in my case?

Tags: javascript, regex

If the RegExp is defined global and I use the `vals` array like I do, the result of exec will be the same everytime, so the code below is an infinity loop.

```js
var regex = RegExp(/<(.*?)>.*?<\/\1>/, "g");

function readXml(xmlString) {
  var obj = {};
  var vals;
  for (var i = 0;
    (vals = regex.exec(xmlString)) !== null; i++) {
    if (!obj[vals[1]]) obj[vals[1]] = [];
    obj[vals[1]].push(readXml(vals[0].slice(vals[1].length + 1, -vals[1] - length - 3)));
  }
  if (i == 0) return xmlString;
  return obj;
}
console.log(readXml("<a>a</a><b>b</b>"));
```

If the RegExp is defined in function, the result of exec will be the next match everytime, so the code below logs a and b.

```js
function readXml(xmlString) {
  var regex = RegExp(/<(.*?)>.*?<\/\1>/, "g");
  var obj = {};
  var vals;
  for (var i = 0;
    (vals = regex.exec(xmlString)) !== null; i++) {
    if (!obj[vals[1]]) obj[vals[1]] = [];
    obj[vals[1]].push(readXml(vals[0].slice(vals[1].length + 1, -vals[1] - length - 3)));
  }
  if (i == 0) return xmlString;
  return obj;
}
console.log(readXml("<a>a</a><b>b</b>"));
```

If I do something else with `vals` arrray in the loop, the result of exec will be the next match everytime, so the code below logs an empty object.

```js
var regex = RegExp(/<(.*?)>.*?<\/\1>/, "g");

function readXml(xmlString) {
  var obj = {};
  var vals;
  for (var i = 0;
    (vals = regex.exec(xmlString)) !== null; i++) {
    vals = [2]
  }
  if (i == 0) return xmlString;
  return obj;
}
console.log(readXml("<a>a</a><b>b</b>"));
```

I think it should be an object with a and b in the first case too.

Why doesn't it just do the same thing in all cases?

Comment: Just because *someone* has to say it: You **can't** correctly process XML with a naive regular expression like that. You need to use a parser. There's an XML parser built into the browser, and several available for other environments. There's no reason not to use one.

Comment: The fundamental answer to *"Why doesn't it just do the same thing in all cases?"* is that regular expression objects **have state** (when you use the `g` flag): They remember where the last match was, and continue from that point. In some places above, you're reusing the same object. In other places, you're creating a new one each time. Hence the differences.

Comment: Also note that `var regex = RegExp(/<(.*?)>.*?<\/\1>/, "g");` is an error-prone way to write `var regex = /<(.*?)>.*?<\/\1>/g;`, which would be the preferred way.

Comment: i know that (there is a parser for xml), but just need to parse very simple xml without attributes and so on. And i couldnt find another example.

Comment: Everyone always thinks "Oh, but my example is simple and well-contained." It is until it isn't, and moreover, why waste your time? Use a parser.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just to add to the regex with the **g** flag being stateful - this function is recursive, so if the regex is in the global scope, then the state of the regex is shared between each invocation of `readXml`. In the second case, the state persists just for *each* execution of `readXml`, so when it recursively calls itself, a new regex keeping track of its own state is created.

Answer (score 0):

Global regexes (ie. using the `g` flag) keep track of the position of the last match in order to successfully get the next one the next time you call `exec`. It makes the assumption that you're passing the same input string each time, but if you go and change the input then it goes weird.

```js
const regex = RegExp(/./,'g'); // should match each character, one at a time.

let input1 = 'test', match;
match = regex.exec(input1);
console.log(match[0]);

// now let's "re-use" the regex object...
let input2 = 'another test';
match = regex.exec(input2);
console.log(match[0]);

console.log("Where did the `a` go??");
```

You can access and modify the property responsible for this behaviour via `regex.lastIndex`, although in this case your best solution is to create a new `RegExp` object within the function, since you're working recursively.

Comment: If this is what's wrong with the OP's code (I didn't go into the code deeply enough to decide), isn't this just a duplicate of [*Why does a RegExp with global flag give wrong results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah probably. Oops.